# Openssl is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk, keytool

I wish to generate an application signature for my app which will later be integrated with Facebook. In one of Facebook's tutorials, I found this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

In the tutorial, it says that by running this cmd, my process of generating the signature will start.

However, this command gives an error:

```
openssl is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Download and install [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/).

Comment: I downloaded 3 of them no one is compatible :/

Comment: What does that mean, khurram?

Comment: I downloaded many versions of openssl from the link u gave but each of them gives an error before installation that it isnt compatible with windows 7- 64 bit. Can you tell me the exact openssl i require

Comment: you can get it from the link I have posted in my ans below...

Comment: Related post - [How to install OpenSSL in windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50625283/465053)

Answer (score 441, accepted):

Well at the place of OpenSSL ... you have to put actually the path to your OpenSSL folder that you have downloaded. Your actual command should look like this:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | "C:\Users\abc\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\abc\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

Remember, the path that you will enter will be the path where you have installed the OpenSSL.

**Edit:**

you can download OpenSSL for windows 32 and 64 bit from the respective links below:

[OpenSSL for 64 Bits](http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip)

[OpenSSL for 32 Bits](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip)

Comment: it says c:\openssl\bin\openssl is not recognized

Comment: a better way would be to execute the original command from openssl/bin directory. I.e if my openssl directory is in C:dev, I would move to C:\dev\openssl\bin, and execute the command  as it is

Comment: you should point out the openssl.exe file: exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android
/debug.keystore | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\op
enssl.exe" base64

Comment: @LatentBoy yess you are right. your way worked for me. Thanks alot.

Comment: thanks...after trying about an hour, your answer worked for me

Comment: can you suggest openssl for windows32bit plse

Comment: @Harsha Please see the edit section, now it has got OPenSSL link for 32 bits as well.

Comment: Usama : Could you please guide on the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935267/how-to-create-keystore-jks-and-create-private-der-and-public-der-cert-file ?

Comment: The download links available seems to be source files and so it doesn't contain binary files which I believe I may have to build myself out of the box. Where can I get the official binary files?

Comment: It should be something like this: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\jaimemontoya\.android\debug.keystore | "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\openssl.exe" base64

Comment: '"C:\OpenSSL\bin.openssl.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: FYI: Usually the debug.keystore password is just "android".

Comment: Remove double quotes and it will work :) 
 like so :
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe base64

Answer (score 36):

Please follow these step, I hope your key working properly:

1. **Step 1** You will  need  OpenSSL. You can download the binary from [openssl-for-windows](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/) project on Google Code.
2. **Step 2** Unzip the folder, then copy the path to the `bin` folder to the clipboard.

   For example, if the file is unzipped to the location `C:\Users\gaurav\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32`, then copy the path `C:\Users\gaurav\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin`.
3. **Step 3** Add the path to your system environment path. After your `PATH` environment variable is set, open the cmd and type this command:

   ```
   C:\>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore [path to debug.keystore] | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
   ```

   Type your password when prompted. If the command works, then you will be shown a key.

Comment: FYI: Usually the debug.keystore password is just "android".

Comment: It is good idea to add path in system environment variable

Answer (score 25):

Use the entire path, like this:

```
exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android
/debug.keystore | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\op
enssl.exe" base64
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

it's late answer but it will help to lazy people like me.. add this code to your Application class, there is no need to download openssl and no need to set the path.. only need is just copy this code.. and keyHash will generated in log.

```
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        printKeyHash();
    }

    private void printKeyHash() {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.i("KeyHash:",
                        Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("jk", "Exception(NameNotFoundException) : " + e);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("mkm", "Exception(NoSuchAlgorithmException) : " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

and do not forget add MyApplication class in manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
</application>
```

Comment: does this work for release version of facebook? if not how?

Comment: This code is used to generate keyhash. And its same key for release too. For release version make sure that you set  public access in facebook developer console.

Comment: Getting error " Both context and applicationId must be non-null", when used above code. @SagarChavada

Answer (score 11):

This is worked for me successfully.

**"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias sociallisting -keystore "D:\keystore\SocialListing" | "C:\cygwin\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\cygwin\bin\openssl.exe" base64**

Be careful with below path :

- **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\keytool.exe"**
- **"D:\keystore\SocialListing"** or it can be like this "**C:\Users\Shaon.android\debug.keystore**"
- **"C:\cygwin\bin\openssl.exe"** or can be like this **C:\Users\openssl\bin\openssl.exe**

If command successfully work then you will see this command :

**Enter keystore password : typeyourpassword**

**Encryptedhashkey****

Answer (score 8):

If you are on windows and if you have git installed then you can run the open ssl command using GIT Bash.

1. go to the directory where you want to store the key
2. Right-click and open the GIT Bash
3. Here you can run any openssl command. e.g.

   `openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k test -P -md sha1`

Answer (score 6):

First navigate to your Java/jre/bin folder in cmd
cd c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin

Then use : [change debug.keystore path to the correct location on your system]
install openssl (for windows 32 or 64 as per your needs at c:\openssl )

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\vibhor\.android\debug.keystore" | "c:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "c:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

So the whole command goes like this : [prompts to enter keystore password on execution ]

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
-keystore "C:\Users\vibhor\.android\debug.keystore" | "c:\openssl\bin\openssl.ex
e" sha1 -binary | "c:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64
Enter keystore password:
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Steps to create Hash Key. 
1: Download openssl from Openssl for Windows . I downloaded the Win64 version 
2:Unzip and copy all the files in the bin folder including openssl.exe(All file of bin folder) 
3:Goto to the folder where you installed JDK for me it’s C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin 
4:Paste all the files you copied from Openssl’s bin folder to the Jdk folder.
```

then go  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin and press shift key and right click and open cmd

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin>//cmd path
```

**that is for Sha1  past this**
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore  "C:\User\ABC\.android.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
  //and ABC is system name put own system name

Comment: What `bin` folder are you refering to in the second step?

Answer (score 2):

I used this code:

This is worked for me successfully.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias sociallisting -
keystore "D:\keystore\SocialListing" | "C:\cygwin\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | 
"C:\cygwin\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

Answer (score 2):

**Downloads and Unzip**

You can download openssl for windows 32 and 64 bit from the respective links below:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads

OpenSSL for 64 Bits  OpenSSL for 32 Bits

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | **"C:\Users\keshav.gera\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin**\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | **"C:\Users\keshav.gera\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin**\openssl.exe" base64
```

**Important**  change our path Here as well as install open ssl in your system

It's Working No Doubt

```
C:\Users\keshav.gera>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | "C:\Users\keshav.gera\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\keshav.gera\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

Enter keystore password:  **android**

```
**ZrRtxw36xWNYL+h3aJdcCeQQxi0=**
```

=============================================================

## using Manually  through Coding

```
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


private void PrintHashKey() {

        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("**com.keshav.patanjalidemo  Your Package Name Here**", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");        
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

IDK if this is relevant here, but if you have Git Installed, you can find the openssl in the "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" and that location you can use in the Terminal for your Keystore Command.

oh and yeah the command:

keytool -exportcert -alias keystore -keystore "C:\Users\YOURPATH/filename.jks" | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl" base64

Comment: This worked.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use this worked for me. please change your Path

C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin  keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Ace.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\openssl\bin

\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64

Comment: must download openssl from here  https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip and copy bin folder and paste to C:\openssl\

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a more recent location to install a windows binary version of openssl (32bit and 64bit) you can find it here:

http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

An up to date list of websites that offer binary distributions is here

http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed that generating hashkey with this single openssl method will work.
If it does not work for me. But thanks for giving me a direction to solve my issue.

Guaranteed Solution :
You need to break the whole command in separate commands and have to write output of every execution in file.

You can take the help from the following link :

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

go to bin folder path in cmd and then run following command

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

you will get your key hash

Answer (score 0):

for windows users download open ssl from google's code repository https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list

After the download, extract the contents to a folder preferably in your c: drive.

Then update your PATH environment variable so you can use the .exe from any location in your command line.

[windows 8] To update your PATH environment variable, click my computer->properties->Advanced System Settings.

Click the Advanced Tab and click the 'Environment Variable' button at the bottom of the dialog then select the Path entry from the 'System Variables' Section by clicking edit.

Paste the path to the bin folder of the extracted openssl download and click ok.

You will need to close and open and command prompt you may have previously launched so that you can load the updated path settings.

Now run this command:

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Oladipo.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

You should see the developer key.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
C:\Users\example>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore 
"C:\Users\example\.android" | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary 
| "C:\openssl\bin\oenssl.exe" base64
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who arrive lost as I was now, follow Usama Sarwar response
but if:

> "your_openssl_path/bin/openssl.exe"

doesn't work, try it

> your_openssl_path/bin/openssl.exe.

Without the quotes.

> "c:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" => Didn't work for me

> c:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe => Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue today, solved it by following this video (the SSL installation) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoAc1lpfK8I&ab_channel=GleyGames

Then, i've took Usamas command, and run it (after changing the paths in the command), I've run it FROM inside the bin folder inside the java installation, using CMD.

full command that worked for me:

**(from inside C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin)** :

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl" base64
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Download SSL for windows at https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads.

**Step 2**

Unzip the folder to OpenSSL and paste it to "*C:\Program Files*".

**Step 3**

Add "*C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\bin*" to your environnement variables (Edit the system environnement variables > Environnement variables > Path > New). It will make openssl work in the terminal.

**Step 4**

Add "*C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin*" to your environnement variables. It will make keytool work in the terminal.

**Step 5**

Open a terminal and execute :

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore .android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

The password should be android.

Answer (score 0):

**use this**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | "C:\Users\DK\openssl-0.9.8d_X64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\DK\openssl-0.9.8d_X64\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution if you have git installed locally.
you can just open git bash, change directory where you want your keys will be generated and then run your command.
it will work because git installs open ssl exe by default and your don't need to set path to your ssl exe manually each time you want to run it.
it works for me and I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried almost everything that was mentioned as a solution here but that didn't work for me. If you are on windows and have Git installed, just do the below and you will get it in a sec;

```bash
1. Open Git Bash
2.keytool -exportcert -alias authFB -keystore "c:\users\your name\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows and have Git Bash installed, you can resolve this issue by running the command in Git Bash. Here's how you can do it:

1. Open Git Bash.
2. Navigate to the directory where you want to generate the application signature.
3. Run the following command:

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

You may need these as well:

- Make sure you have installed Git Bash on your Windows system. You can download it from the official Git website: https://git-scm.com/download/win
- Ensure that you're running the command in the correct directory. If you're not sure, you can use the **pwd** command to check the current working directory.