# error in Generating App Signature for Facebook Settings

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

[Following this to generate app signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896304/openssl-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)
but getting invalid commands with different symbols, here I am attaching the
[image: screenshot]
downloaded openssl which is specified in the above link.

Comment: What is the error?It isnt obvious from this pic

Comment: please see the picture..

Comment: I cant click it and the letters are too small...provide another link please!

Comment: Rclick and view image..

Comment: Its not clickable dude!

Answer (score 0):

Follow EXACTLY this line!!

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | "C:\Users\abc\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\abc\openssl" base64
```

Comment: still having the same problem.'"C:\Users\abc\openssl" here openssl folder path or path of openssl file in bin folder

Comment: You specify the openssl folder there

Comment: C:\Users\jp\.android>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\jp\.android\debug.keystore | "C:\Users\jp\Desktop\openssl" sha1 -bi
nary | "C:\Users\jp\openssl" base64
'"C:\Users\jp\Desktop\openssl"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.