# openssl issues: generating application signature

Tags: java, android, facebook, openssl, command-prompt

I am trying to integrate Facebook with my application.I read that i had to install OpenSSL which i downloaded and installed. now the problem is that i want to generate the application signature and i, using the cmd, wrote the following as instructed:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keyst
ore "C:\Users\Andre\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl ba
se64
```

All i got was an error saying:
'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or a batch file.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896304/openssl-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Try just `openssl version` to ensure OpenSSL is on-path.

Comment: i have fixed it. i followed the link given to me by Marco and it worked like a charm. Thanks Marco, you have my vote.