# Cordova facebook invalid hash key

Tags: facebook, cordova, hash, cordova-plugins, cordova-facebook

I am trying to do facebook login for a hybrid app. However, when I try to log in using Facebook, I get this error message:

> Invalid key hash. The key hash gawWYqXiaXXXXXXXXX.... does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.face......

I tried to copy the hash key as displayed on the message and add in to my facebook developer account key hashes, but it still popup the same error message.

How can I overcome it?

---Update---

Just now I tried with my colleague PC by building app on his PC then try to login to Facebook. When I face the error message above, I copy the key hash and put into facebook. Then I try again, it work!!!!

Why it doesn't work for my PC? Btw, I am following the answer from ([Openssl is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896304/openssl-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)) to create the hash key. The generated hash key is different than the hash key that I saw on the app. Is there anything wrong with my PC that cause the error? How can I fix it?

Comment: What are you trying debug apk or released apk?

Comment: @NehilMistry I am trying to do debugging.

Comment: For debugging you must locate `debug.keystore`, try getting keyhash and add it in facebook app. If keyhash is correct is should work perfectly.

Comment: @NehilMistry Yeah, I am locate `debug.keystore` file (the file is 3 years old) and I have tried to add both key hash (one from PC, another one from the message) to facebook app, but none of them work. I really don't get the sense why it doesn't work on the app build from my PC.