# Cannot generate debug.keystore in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore, android-facebook, android-keystore

I am developing an Android project. I am doing Facebook Login Integration. I have never published an apk on Playstore yet. Never released an official apk yet. Now I am having problem with Facebook integration now. The problem is creating Facebook hash key.

I am following this link,[How to create Android Facebook Key Hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash) to generate Facebook Hash Key . Other links I found also just showing same solution. It requires debug.keystore path. So I tried to generate it from Android Studio. I am using Android Studio version 1.4. I tried the following ways and I still do not get debug.keystore to generate Facebook Hash Key.

I generate Signed APK in debug mode as follow

[image]

I opened the folded after successful operation. But only jks file exists in folder and there is no debug.keystore. I searched other solutions and I found this link,[Where is debug.keystore in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965058/where-the-debug-keystore-in-android-studio) and followed it.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I named the storefile name as debug.keystore and clicked ok. All credentials are just the same as first way and folder same as well. But when I open folder, there is no debug.keystore file. Then I tried to run my project still working or not. It gave me error and I renamed the keystore file name from debug.keystore to jks file name that I created in the first way. So why debug.keystore file is not generated, and how can I generate it?

Comment: are you tried with .jks file? store file name should be fashion_network.jks

Comment: In openssl terminal command to generate facebook hash key? Path to jks file in command?

Comment: keytool -exportcert -alias <your_keystore> alias -keystore <your_keystore_file> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Comment: I open openssl.exe and run command. But it is saying "keytool" is invalid command. Why?

Comment: I opened terminal double-clicked on exe file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117710/discussion-between-clifford-and-wai-yan-hein).

Comment: I got hash key. I followed the green answer of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896304/openssl-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command . Run command from keytool terminal. Thanks so much for your support. @Clifford