# CMake cannot find OpenSSL

Tags: android, cmake, openssl

This seems like a frequent issue but I can't figure it out...

I'm trying to compile some libraries which use OpenSSL. They use CMake and are unable to find OpenSSL, even though I made a local build of BoringSSL and set OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR to its install directory.

To work on the issue more easily, I made a test CMakeLists.txt, here it is completely:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

project(test)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
```

This fails with:

```
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

I do have `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` environment variable set to the `install` directory inside my local BoringSSL build:

```
% echo $OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR
/Users/[...]/deps/boringssl/cmake-build-debug-arm64-v8a/install
```

The files are there:

```
% ls $OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR/include/openssl/                                             (main|…6)
aead.h          cipher.h        engine.h
....... ssl.h

% ls $OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR/lib                                                          (main|…6)
libcrypto.a libssl.a
```

I that know CMake (specifically FindOpenSSL.cmake) looks for `openssl/ssl.h` under `include` like this:

```
find_path(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES
    openssl/ssl.h
  ${_OPENSSL_ROOT_HINTS_AND_PATHS}
  HINTS
    ${_OPENSSL_INCLUDEDIR}
    ${_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  PATH_SUFFIXES
    include
)
```

I even hacked FindOpenSSL.cmake to print out `_OPENSSL_ROOT_HINTS_AND_PATHS` here it is:

```
STATUS,*** Hints and paths = HINTS;/Users/[...]/deps/boringssl/cmake-build-debug-arm64-v8a/install;ENV;OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR;PATHS
```

Which has the right path already, plus it refers to the `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` environment variable.

And yet I still get the error.

This seems almost magical and in a bad way. Any ideas?

I've tried using cmake 3.22.1 from the Android SDK and the native (MacOS) cmake 3.24.3, both error out the same way.

Also tried:

```
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR .......)
```

right CMakeLists.txt, same error. Magic!

***Update***

The error is caused by

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
```

If I remove it, the error goes away.

Yes I'm trying to compile for Android. So the Android toolchain is somehow messing up CMake's ability to find OpenSSL. I am using the latest NDK, 25.1.8937393.

Comment: As far as I know, toolchain for Android prevents CMake to search packages under the host, so all dependent package should be installed under `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`. See e.g. that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791251/possible-causes-for-boost-not-being-found-by-cmake-in-certain-situations/35806563#35806563).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is detailed description of why this happens here:

[Android CMake: Could NOT find OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958214)

This works for me:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "$ENV{OPENSSL_CUSTOM_ROOT_DIR}")
find_package(OpenSSL)
```