# How to generate CSR for ssl certificate in heroku for a custom domain?

Tags: laravel, ssl, heroku

I have a laravel app running on heroku with a custom domain. I'd like the domain to have my own ssl certificate that I've purchased. From where I've purchased the domain they are requesting for CSR from heroku. I've got no idea how to do this. Tried researching and reading their documentation but I don't seem to understand how to go about it. Any assistance ill be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your project folder on your local machine.(or clone from github if you dont)

enter this command accordingly

1. openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.pass.key 2048
2. openssl rsa -in server.pass.key -out server.key
3. openssl req -nodes -new -key server.key -out server.csr

follow the prompt to set password etc..

if you havent setup open ssl on your machine before this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896304/openssl-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) will give you a solution