# How to Fix NO_SECRET warning thrown by Next-Auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have a Next js application that uses Next Auth. While in development I continuously keep getting that warning stipulating that I need to set a secret but I don't know where I should set it.

Following this [reference](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#secret) I see I just need to run `openssl rand -base64 32` to get a secret but I have no Idea where to put it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the [...nextauth].js outside provider and callback you can set the secret and it's value. As it is recommended to store such values in environment variable you can do the following

```
export default NextAuth({
 
  providers: [ 
  ],
  callbacks: {
  },
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
});
```

Comment: This is working with only one provider,
what if there are more than one provider?

Answer (score 13):

You should insert the command `openssl rand -base64 32`in your Linux terminal, then it will generate a Token to use it on an .env file with the variable name `NEXTAUTH_SECRET=token_generated`. So the error `[next-auth][warn][NO_SECRET]` will not be showed again on console.

Answer (score 9):

In my case i had to upgrade `next` and `next-auth` module to the latest version.
`next@12.1.6` and `next-auth@4.5.0` worked for me.

```
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=secret string here
```

You can generate secret key using this command line `openssl rand -base64 32` in command prompt or windows power shell.

And in the next-auth configuration `[...nextauth].ts` file

```
export default NextAuth({
 
  providers: [ 
  ],
  callbacks: {
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
});
```

It is said if secret is not defined in `[...nextauth].ts`, it loads `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` from `env`, but I added it and works like charm. :)

Comment: The command you said neither works in CMD nor PS.

Comment: link to possible solution @AliBahaari
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896304/openssl-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently on a Vercel deployment

I solved it with the following steps:

1. Create `NEXTAUTH_URL` and `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` on `.env` (the URL is your domain and the secret is any hash)
2. Go on your settings project on Vercel and add `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` on your Environment Variables (same secret of your `.env`)

I'm using middleware and the code is:

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"
export const config = { matcher: ["/admin/dashboard/", "/admin/dashboard/:path*"] }
```